# Get image from table cell via Google Sheets API

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am getting table values via query:
`GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range}`
But the cell with the image has an empty value.
How can I get an image from a cell through a query?

The image was inserted into the table without a formula (there is no link to the image in the formula).

Comment: How were your images put into the cells of Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: Through pasting from the buffer, without url

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Through pasting from the buffer, without url`, in this case, unfortunately, in the current stage, those images cannot be retrieved using Sheets API.